# How to handle multiple getDistanceMatrix calls in the google api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to make multiple calls to the google api, especially the function `google.maps.DistanceMatrixService().getDistanceMatrix` with a list of destination points. Each call has a point of origin and multiple destinations.

How can I 'map' the result of each call to the input parameters? What I mean is, I have several requests running, and each request calls the callback function on completion. Now, the callback function unfortunately does not receive the original destination information (i.e. a `google.maps.LatLng` object) but just a string [see here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DistanceMatrixResponse) ('destinationAddresses'), which I now must again convert into a `google.maps.LatLng` object...

Is there any other way to identify the content of a 'response' object with the list of `google.maps.LatLng` objects that were given to  `google.maps.DistanceMatrixService().getDistanceMatrix`?

Comment: Map it with promises https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md ... Then switch to OSRM

Comment: parsing it is not enough? [**doc**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_parsing_the_results)

Comment: What do you mean, 'parsing'? I just want to have something like `distance = getDistance(origin, destination)`...